# Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: hudson.util.DescribableList

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Not sure why I'm getting this exception in Jenkins - code works and the env is setup properly.

Can anyone help me with the exception. Because of that the job is marked as failed

Exception:

```
an exception which occurred:
    in field groovy.lang.Closure.delegate
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@2a0e2882
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.closures
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@123f9c25
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@123f9c25
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: hudson.util.DescribableList
```

Code:

```
def setGlobalParameter(destination) {
    nodes = Jenkins.instance.globalNodeProperties
    nodes.getAll(hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.class)
    
    if ( nodes.size() != 1 ) {
      println("error: unexpected number of environment variable containers: ${nodes.size()}, expected: 1")
    } else {
      envVars = nodes[0].envVars
      if (destination) {
        envVars["XXX"] = "staging"
      } else {
        envVars["XXX"] = ""
      }
      Jenkins.instance.save()
    }
    
    return "Done"
}
node() {

setGlobalParameter(true)
}
```

Comment: Does the code work, or is it throwing an exception? You claim both in the question.

Comment: The code works and also the exception is thrown

Comment: Instead of node.getall try to fetch using loop one of your environment variable is having an issue